# MP3 decoder using IPP

Tags: mp3, intel-ipp

I need an mp3 decoder (no need for encoding), and since I already own Intel IPP, I wonder if I can use it instead searching for other libraries such as mpg123 or ffmpeg. This page contains IPP sample archive:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/code-samples-for-intel-integrated-performance-primitives-intel-ipp-v61-library

There is something called UMC, which should be generalized codec system, but the documentation is virtually nonexistent, it is spread between many subprojects and the downloads are different for Windows & Mac.

Is UMC the right way to go to get an MP3 decoder? Does it work on both Windows & Mac?